# reload a PHP condition with ajax (Woocommerce)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, woocommerce

I have added one custom field (select tag) to checkout page that is output of two conditions:

1st >> If "Victoria" state is selected then display first condition as custom field.

2nd >> If any other state is selected then display second condition as custom field.

```
// Add custom checkout datepicker field to checkout page

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'checkout_display_datepicker_custom_field' );
function checkout_display_datepicker_custom_field( $checkout ) {
    
    echo '<div id="datepicker-wrapper" style="width:22%;">';
    
       $field_id = 'my_datepicker';
       $state_code = 'VIC';
       $today = strtotime('today');
       $tomorrow = strtotime('tomorrow');
       $dayAfterTomorrow = strtotime('+2 days');
    
// First Condition, If "VICTORIA" is selected

 if( WC()->customer->get_billing_state() === $state_code ){
     
     woocommerce_form_field(  $field_id, array(
        'type'          => 'select',
        'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
        'label' => __('Delivery Date For Victoria'),
        'placeholder'   => __('Select Delivery Date For Victoria'),
        'required' => true, // Or false
        'options'     => array(
            '' => 'Select',
            date(('d F Y'), $today ) => date(('d F Y'), $today ),
            date(('d F Y'), $tomorrow ) => date(('d F Y'), $tomorrow ),
        )));

     echo '<br></div>';
     
        } else {

 // Second Condition, If other state is selected
        
        woocommerce_form_field(  $field_id, array(
        'type'          => 'select',
        'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
        'label' => __('Delivery Date'),
        'placeholder'   => __('Select Delivery Date'),
        'required' => true, // Or false
        'options'     => array(
            '' => 'Select',
            date(('d F Y'), $tomorrow ) => date(('d F Y'), $tomorrow ),
            date(('d F Y'), $dayAfterTomorrow ) => date(('d F Y'), $dayAfterTomorrow ),
        )));

     echo '<br></div>';                 

        }  
}
```

Then I need a jQuery to reload above conditions on every state change and display custom field based on choosed state, I tried this script but it doesn't work:

```
//jQuery to refresh custom field (delivery date) based on choosed state

add_action('wp_ajax_woo_modify_state', 'delivery_date', 10);
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_woo_modify_state', 'delivey_date', 10);

function delivery_date() {
    // On checkout
    if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#billing_state').change(function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: wc_checkout_params.ajax_url,
            type: "post",
            data: {option: jQuery(this).find("option:selected").val()},
            success: function(data){
                //adds the echoed response to our container
                jQuery("#my_datepicker").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});

    </script>
    
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Am I using a correct method to reload a PHP condition with ajax? I don't see any error on console and that is why I am confused with it.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What have you tried to check **why** anything is not working as expected?

Comment: PHP code works but jQuery is not working as expected.

Comment: @NicoHaase is `url: wc_checkout_params.ajax_url,` correct?

Comment: is there any error message you could share? What does "not working" mean **exactly**? Is the request sent properly? Does it contain the expected data? Or is the response not handled properly?

Comment: @NicoHaase No I don't see any error in console. How can I find out the request is sent properly? Currently when I change billing state no change happens in custom checkout datepicker field.

Comment: That's what you could check in your browser's developer console, or by debugging the PHP script

Comment: @NicoHaase in the browser's developer console there is no hint! How can I debug the PHP script!? because I don't have any php error in browser too; Is there any special tool for it?

Comment: Debugging PHP code is possible through var_dump, XDebug,.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to run Ajax at all. WooCommerce refreshes the checkout page after changing the default fields automatically. The following code is what you need:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_submit', 'ywp_conditional_delivery_field' );
function ywp_conditional_delivery_field() {
    $state_code = 'VIC';

    if( $selected_state_code = WC()->customer->get_billing_state() ) {
        $country_code = WC()->customer->get_billing_country();
        $state_name   = WC()->countries->get_states( $country_code )[$state_code];

        if( WC()->customer->get_billing_state() === $state_code ) {
            $field_id           = 'my_datepicker';
            $today              = strtotime( 'today' );
            $tomorrow           = strtotime( 'tomorrow' );
            $dayAfterTomorrow   = strtotime( '+2 days' );

            woocommerce_form_field( $field_id, array(
                'type'          => 'select',
                'class'         => array( 'form-row-wide' ),
                'label'         => __( 'Delivery Date For Victoria' ),
                'placeholder'   => __( 'Select Delivery Date For Victoria' ),
                'required'      => true, // Or false
                'options'       => array(
                    ''                          => 'Select',
                    date( ( 'd F Y' ), $today )     => date( ( 'd F Y' ), $today ),
                    date( ( 'd F Y' ), $tomorrow ) => date( ( 'd F Y' ), $tomorrow ),
                )
            ) );
        } else {
            woocommerce_form_field(  $field_id, array(
                'type'          => 'select',
                'class'         => array( 'form-row-wide' ),
                'label'         => __( 'Delivery Date' ),
                'placeholder'   => __( 'Select Delivery Date' ),
                'required'      => true, // Or false
                'options'       => array(
                    '' => 'Select',
                    date( ( 'd F Y' ), $tomorrow ) => date( ( 'd F Y' ), $tomorrow ),
                    date( ( 'd F Y' ), $dayAfterTomorrow ) => date( ( 'd F Y' ), $dayAfterTomorrow ),
                )
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

The following code works correctly to display the shipping date before the order note that you need it:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'ywp_conditional_delivery_field' );
function ywp_conditional_delivery_field() {
    $today              = date( 'd F Y' ,strtotime( 'today' ) );
    $tomorrow           = date( 'd F Y' ,strtotime( 'tomorrow' ) );
    $dayAfterTomorrow   = date( 'd F Y' ,strtotime( '+2 days' ) );
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $('#billing_state').on('change',function(){
                if($(this).val()=='VIC'){
                    $('#my_non_VIC_datepicker_field').remove();
                    $('#order_comments_field').prepend('<p class="form-row form-row-wide validate-required" id="my_VIC_datepicker_field" data-priority=""><label for="my_VIC_datepicker" class="">Delivery Date For Victoria&nbsp;<abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label><span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper"><select name="my_VIC_datepicker" id="my_VIC_datepicker" class="select " data-allow_clear="true" data-placeholder="Select Delivery Date For Victoria"><option value=""  selected="selected">Select</option><option value="<?php echo $today; ?>" ><?php echo $today; ?></option><option value="<?php echo $tomorrow; ?>"><?php echo $tomorrow; ?></option></select></span></p>');
                } else {
                    $('#my_VIC_datepicker_field').remove();
                    $('#order_comments_field').prepend('<p class="form-row form-row-wide validate-required" id="my_non_VIC_datepicker_field" data-priority=""><label for="my_non_VIC_datepicker_field" class="">Delivery Date&nbsp;<abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label><span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper"><select name="my_non_VIC_datepicker" id="my_non_VIC_datepicker" class="select " data-allow_clear="true" data-placeholder="Select Delivery Date"><option value=""  selected="selected">Select</option><option value="<?php echo $today; ?>" ><?php echo $today; ?></option><option value="<?php echo $tomorrow; ?>"><?php echo $tomorrow; ?></option><option value="<?php echo $dayAfterTomorrow; ?>"><?php echo $dayAfterTomorrow; ?></option></select></span></p>');
                }
            });
        })
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in `functions.php` of your active theme/child theme. Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks! But still I have an issue; Why your code doesn't work with `woocommerce_before_order_notes`? And also your code doesn't display **placeholder** but `woocommerce_before_order_notes` does.

Comment: you're welcome. Because the order note is not updated by changing the WooCommerce fields. Also, the **select** tag does not receive a **placeholder** value. **This is from html restrictions**, not from my code :)

Comment: Ok, so what can I do to display custom field exactly before order notes or just after order details table? And why `woocommerce_before_order_notes` can display **placeholder** of select tag?

Comment: @omid-toraby I edited the code. The reason that __country__ and __state__ fields have a **placeholder** is that WooCommerce uses [select2](https://select2.org/) to make these two fields searchable. You can apply the changes yourself using the documentation.

Comment: @omid-toraby You should also save the values when ordering and display it in the order management counter. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49931749/9448527) will help you.

Comment: Edited code duplicates the select field like [this screenshot](https://imgur.com/jx363KF)

Comment: Your primitive code is also usable for me but I don't know why form is enabled to submit when no option of select field is selected? Select field loads as required field but user can place order even without choosing any delivery date.

Comment: I solved required field issue by using jQuery, Thanks again!